# Why is the entropy of a binary digit maximised if both outcomes are equiprobable?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

One elementary result of Information Theory is that a binary digit communicates the most information when used to distinguish between two equally probable events, e.g. a toss of an unbiased coin.

Another way to think about this is that each binary digit must half the set of outcomes for a coding to be efficient, i.e.

- 0 enables you to eliminate 50% of the search space
- 1 enables you to eliminate 50% of the search space

where both 0 and 1 occur with equal probability.

What if you had a binary code where

- 0 enables you to eliminate 30% of the search space
- 1 enables you to eliminate 70% of the search space

where 0 occurs with 0.7 probability, and 1 occurs with 0.3 probability.

Isn't this, on average, equally efficient as the binary code where both 0 and 1 are equally probable and each eliminates 50% of the search space?

Comment: In your example, $70\%$ of the time you still have $70\%$ of the work left to do, and $30\%$ of the time you still have $30\%$ of the work left to do, so on average you have $58\%$ of the work left to do; when each bit eliminates $50\%$ of the search space, you have only $50\%$ of the work left to do after the first bit. It’s easier to see intuitively in a more extreme case: If a $0$ eliminates only $1\%$ of the search space, while a $1$ eliminates $99\%$, a $0$ tells you almost nothing: after receiving it, you’re still practically as ignorant as when you started.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I arrived at the same numbers; what I'm struggling with is the intuitive grasp. "Intuitively" it is reasonable to expect these to be equivalent to the 50/50 case, because, "intuitively", in your example, though a 1 is much less likely, it also eliminates more of the search space. It seems like an balanced trade off, if that makes sense, for frequency vs reduction in the search space. I wish there was some sort of geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not on average equally efficient. Averaging the percentages like that can't work; if you replace 30% with a much smaller probability, say 1%, then it might be clearer intuitively that eliminating 1% of the search space 99% of the time and eliminating 99% of the search space 1% of the time isn't that great, because the second case just doesn't occur that often.

The correct thing to do is to average the *number of bits you've gained* (which is equivalent to taking a geometric mean instead of an arithmetic mean), as follows: if you eliminate a proportion $1 - p$ of the search space with probability $p$, the size of the search space has been reduced by a factor of $p$, so you've gained $\log_{1/2} p$ bits of information with probability $p$. If the other case is that you eliminate $p$ of the search space with probability $1 - p$, then you've gained $\log_{1/2} (1 - p)$ bits of information with probability $1 - p$. So on average the number of bits you've gained is

$$p \log_{1/2} p + (1 - p) \log_{1/2} (1 - p) = H(p)$$

which is exactly the (binary) entropy, which is maximized when $p = \frac{1}{2}$ as usual (e.g. using calculus, although other approaches are possible, for example [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)).

One way you can check that taking the logarithm is a sensible thing to do is that it behaves correctly with respect to gaining more information: if you reduce the search space by a factor of $p$ and then by a factor of $q$, you've overall reduced the search space by a factor of $pq$, which corresponds to a gain of $\log_{1/2} (pq)$ bits being equal to a gain of $\log_{1/2} p$ bits plus a gain of $\log_{1/2} q$ bits.

The best piece of writing I've ever read for gaining intuition about this idea of taking logarithms as a measure of gaining bits of information is actually [this essay by Gwern](https://www.gwern.net/Death-Note-Anonymity) analyzing how the protagonist of Death Note leaks different numbers of bits of information about himself over the course of the anime. Fun stuff.

Comment: That essay you linked is by far the most detailed analysis I've seen of an anime.